# Express Route is not working and always return status 200 response

Tags: reactjs, api, express

I am trying to create POST api route `("/upload")` but then the route isn't working correctly. I think the cause might be from

`app.use((req, res, next) => {   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build", "index.html")); });`

which I followed from a [blog](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-render-react-app-using-express-server-in-node-js-a428ec4dfe2b) when setting up react and express server. I tried testing with Postman and it always get 200 response. Please help!!

**server.js (Express)**

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express(); // create express app
const fileUpload  = require('express-fileUpload');

// add middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build")));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "build", "index.html"));
});

app.use(fileUpload());
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  if (req.files === null) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No file uploaded' });
  }
  const file = req.files.file;
  file.mv(`${__dirname}/public/uploads/${file.name}`, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    res.json({ fileName: file.name, filePath: `/uploads/${file.name}` });
  });
});

// start express server on port 5000
app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("server started on port 5000");
});
```

**index.js (React)**

```
const handleUpload = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    try {
      console.log(file)
      const res = await axios.post('/uploads', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      });

      const { fileName, filePath } = res.data;

      console.log(fileName);
      console.log(filePath);

    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response.status === 500) {
        console.log('There was a problem with the server');
      } else {
        console.log(err.response.data.msg);
      }
    }
  };
```

**POST Result (Postman)**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4ndz.png)

I want to create a POST api route `("/upload")` so that I can save the uploaded file from the `<input type=file/>` in a specific folder. Currently, the API response always getting 200 status but I feel like it actually isn't connecting with the server side routing.

Comment: what does `file.mv()` function do? const file = req.files.file; file is not function! you can't send function from front-end to backend! your `file` variable is assigned by the file property of the files of the req object.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to react and express. I followed from [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6Oe2puTdMQ&t=1618s). From what I understand, the data from the front-end will be sent to backend as `formData named 'file'`. I believe `file.mv()` move/writes the data into the specified folder path. Do you have any recommendations on how I could change it? Thank you!